# Update of an Href button without page reload

Tags: ajax

I'm having trouble with using ajax. Can you help me?

I have an a href button that is labeled Subscribe if $sub is 0 and Unsubscribe if $sub is not.By the way, $sub is a result of a query.
When i clicked it to Subscribe, $sub becomes 1(a row is inserted in database) and the label is changed to Unsubscribed. Without reloading the page, i clicked the button again (now labeled Unsubscribed) but instead of making $sub 0 (deleting the inserted row) it inserted another row in the db instead.

This is my database query for $sub which is in the same page with the href button

```
    $buddy_request = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT count(subscription_id) FROM SUBSCRIPTION    
    WHERE subscriber = '$viewer' and subscribed = '$viewed'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($buddy_request))
    {

     $sub = $row['count(subscription_id)'];  
    }
```

This is the button

```
    <a href='' id='subscribe'  data-sub = '<?php echo $sub; ?>' ><?php if($sub == 0){echo "Subscribe";} else {echo "Unsubscribe";}?></a>
```

Here is my ajax

```
    $("#subscribe").click(function(e) 
        {   
            e.preventDefault();
            var sub = $(this).data('sub');
            //to subscribe
            if(sub == 0)
            {
                $.ajax({
                url: 'subscribe.php',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                context: this,
                success: function(result)
                        {                                           

                            if (result == true)
                            $(this).html('Unsubscribe');    
                        } 
                });
            }
            //to unsubscribe
            else
            {
                $.ajax({
                url: 'unsubscribe.php',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                context: this,
                success: function(result)
                        {                                           
                            if (result == true)
                            $(this).html('Subscribe');  
                        } 
                });
            }

        })
```

and this is subscribe.php

```
   $result = false;
   $sql="INSERT INTO SUBSCRIPTION (subscriber,subscribed)
          VALUES($viewer,$viewed)";
    if (!mysqli_query($connection,$sql))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
    }
    $result = true; 
   echo json_encode($result);
```

I tried using location.reload() in every successful ajax and it is working fine but i do not find it good to look at the page reloading every after the button is clicked. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you try type: 'POST' for modifying server resources? You shouldn't need to reload the page or anything since you're using ajax.

Comment: i still have same result. when i click subscribe it immediately becomes unsubscribed without reloading. The problem is when i clicked it again right after it becomes unsubscribed, instead of unsubscribing, it does the subscribe function. Thanks for the reply, though.

Comment: Another thing is where do you update the 'sub' value? I don't see it. Right now, it's always 0, meaning it would call 'subscribe.php' everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Update your data-sub value inside your success functions

For if branch

```
$(this).data('sub', 1);
```

for else branch

```
$(this).data('sub', 0);
```